# How to install/enable GD in xampp windows [php 7.2]?

Tags: codeigniter, gd

I Can't figure out how to install php-gd for PHP7.2. Is there any way to install/enable GD extension in xampp windows? I checked the php.ini file for **php_gd2.dll** but I can't find that line. It seems like GD is missing in PHP7.2. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 77):

1. go to php.ini file
2. search this `;extension=gd`
3. remove `;`
   then restart the server

Comment: Worked form me on Windows 10 64-bit and XAMPP PHP 8.1.1 64-bit.

Comment: Added extension=gd without semicolon in xampp PHP 8.1.2

Answer (score 23):

Under xampp/php/php.ini look for "extension=gd2" and uncomment it, I presume this what you looking for

Comment: Remember to start stop apache after uncommeting an extension

Comment: It's already enabled. Fixed the issue by correcting the file path. If the file path is invalid it will display the error message "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image." Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Extension 'gd2' not found, but 'gd' does.

Answer (score 11):

8 steps:

1. Open xampp control panel.
2. Start apache and mysql.
3. Click on config option of apache.
4. Click on php.ini and open it.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search "extension=" or "extension=fileinfo".
6. On the next line to "extension=fileinfo", add "extension=gd".
7. Save the file.
8. Stop apache and restart it.

You are done.
My PHP version is 8. if yours is 7 you may need to add extension=gd2 in `php.ini` file.
You can see your PHP version by searching for "localhost/dashboard" in the browser and then clicking on "PHPinfo" at the top right.

if ";extension=gd" is already there, remove the semicolon and save the file and restart Xampp.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with the recent xampp version using php 8

Answer (score 5):

1. open XAMPP control panel
2. click Apache config select PHP(php.ini)
3. ctrl + F , so search for gd
4. you should see a line  like  `;extension=gd`
5. just remove  `;` and save it
6. stop apache and restart
7. Your XAMPP now has GD enable

Answer (score 2):

Also for windows user if you have multiple xampp installed check which php ini is being used by composer by using command

php --ini

if its not the one you are using u can try uninstalling the undesired one and then trying again

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the absolute path to the extension as well:

```
extension=gd
extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

1. open xampp
2. in apache server click config - php.ini
3. go to php.ini file
4. ctrl + f to search this ;extension=gd
5. remove ; then restart the server