# apt-get command not working on xampp, running windows 11

Tags: php, gd, apt-get

I'm facing error in wordpress on my local server  while trying to edin an image, it says **"Image rotation is not supported by your web host."**

I have a Windows 11 64-bit PC that runs a XAMPP.

I need to install a few things on this Apache server via command line, so I'm going to the "shell" option from the Xampp control panel. But when I run the "apt-get" command, it says that **"it is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."**

Comment: `apt-get` is for Debian-based linux servers only. You need to enable php-gd in your XAMPP configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474258/how-to-install-enable-gd-in-xampp-windows-php-7-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get` is only available on Debian-based linux distributions.

Go to your `php.ini` file search for `;extension=gd` remove the `;` and restart the server this should fix your problem.