Cannot use mpdf/mpdf's latest version v8.2.3
My laptop is running windows 11 and has XAMPP control panel V3.3.0.
I have successfully installed composer using composer-setup.
when installing mpdf using 'composer require mpdf/mpdf', occers following error message.
Cannot use mpdf/mpdf's latest version v8.2.3 as it requires ext-gd * which is missing from your platform.<br>
./composer.json has been updated<br>
Running composer update mpdf/mpdf<br>
Loading composer repositories with package information<br>
Updating dependencies<br>
Nothing to modify in lock file<br>
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)<br>
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals<br>
    Failed to download setasign/fpdi from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini<br>
    Now trying to download from source<br>

In GitDownloader.php line 82:

  git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]

Need to install mpdf

Did you check similar posts like this and that?

Did you read the error message? There are multiple parts that you should check: as it requires ext-gd * which is missing or The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing - did you try anything to resolve these warnings?

It simply says that enable ext-gd extension from your php.ini file. If you are very new in the market then refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474417/1817690
